# Changing data types of elements in lists of lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have an imported data file.

It is a list made up of 51 lists.

Each of the nested lists has 5 elements.

I want to change 1 (The second element so location 1) of the 5 elements from string to integers.

This is what I have:

```
for i in range(len(statesData)):
    statesData[i] = statesData[i].strip()
    statesData[i] = statesData[i].split(',')
    for d in statesData[i]:
        d[1] = int(d[1])
        d[2] = float(d[2])
```

Now I don't want element 1 (0) to be included since it is the heading of each category.

I want to start with 2 (1). I was thinking a range function somewhere like:

```
statesData[i][1:]
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any advice? I should be able to do this without too much trouble. Or having to create a function.

Comment: could you please provide an example `statesData`? and the desired output for that example? would really help

Comment: Do you really need to change the list in place ?

Comment: I guess no I do not. I need to change to an integer so I can sum the  categories.

Answer (score 0):

In your second loop, you are looping over each element of the nested lists, i.e. when you're doing `d[1]` you are indexing the string of said element. Try this instead

```py
for i in range(len(statesData)):
    print(statesData[i])
    statesData[i] = statesData[i].strip()
    statesData[i] = statesData[i].split(',')
    statesData[i][1] = int(statesData[i][1])
    statesData[i][2] = float(statesData[i][2])
```

Comment: The code helps.  

['State', 'Population', 'ElectoralVotes', 'HighwayMiles', 'SquareMiles'],
 ['Alabama', '4802982', '9', '213068', '52419.02'],
 ['Alaska', '721523', '3', '31618', '663267.26'],
 ['Arizona', '6412700', '11', '144393', '113998.3'],

But it is still identifying 'population' instead of '4802982'

Comment: That's because the first iteration is the headers, I'm guessing. Just add a check at the start of the loop - something like, if `i` is 0, `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of lists only containing integers similar to this

```
t = [['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'], ['0', '5', '6', '7', '8']]
```

you can change the `type` of all elements except the first for each list with a list comprehension like this:

```
mod_t = [[l[0]] + [int(e) for e in l[1:]] for l in t]
# [['0', 1, 2, 3, 4], ['0', 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

### Explanations:

- You walk through all list elements of `t` with `for l in t`
- For each of those lists, you'll generate a new list with the original first element `l[0]` and integer converted elements for all subsequent items `[int(e) for e in l[1:]]`

Answer (score 0):

First point, semantically, your list should be a list of tuples, not a list of lists (if position is significant then it's a tuple - a list is supposed to be an homogeneous collection).

Also, changing the list in place is mostly a useless complication, specially for such a small dataset. The simplest solution is to build a new list from the existing one, ie:

```
def parse_row(row):
    return (row[0], int(row[1]), float(row[2])) + row[3:]

def parse_data(data):
    return [parse_row(row) for row in data]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    state_data = [
    ("foo", "1", "1.5", "a", "b"),
    ("bar", "2", "2.5", "c", "d"),
    ("baaz", "3", "3.5", "e", "f"),
    ("quux", "4", "4.5", "g", "h"),
    ]
print(parse_data(state_data))
```

wrt/ your issue:

```
for d in statesData[i]:
    d[1] = int(d[1])
    d[2] = float(d[2])
```

here, `statesData[i]` is your current sublist, so the iteration variable `d` is successively rebound to each of your sublist's elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with the following which is pretty concise:

```
for i, sd in enumerate(statesData):  
    sd = sd.strip().split(',')
    if i:  # omit first (index 0) from further processing
        sd[1:3] = int(sd[1]), float(sd[2])
    statesData[i] = sd
```